# How to host a WCF service from one project in another project?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service I created which now needs to be integrated into another project. Instead of standing the service up on its own, I'd like the second project to host the service (it's a Sitecore implementation and will make things easier from a maintenance standpoint). The projects are in different solutions. Is it possible for the second project to serve up the service, even though the code is in another project? I know I need to reference the DLL, but beyond that I'm not sure how to set up the service. I assume I need some kind of partial implementation of the service, but that's the extent of my knowledge.

Another wrinkle - the service is written in VB while the second project is C#. It shouldn't matter because I'm referencing all the service code via the DLL, but I thought I'd mention it.

**UPDATE**
One thing I forgot to mention is that I'd like the service to also be available to other applications as a web service. So the service will stand up inside the second app, so that a third app could call the service. I don't know if this influences any of the responses so far.

Answer (score 3):

If your WCF service is compiled as a DLL, it should be as simple as adding a reference and:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
     host.Open();

     Console.ReadLine();
     host.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I updated my original request with an important piece of missing info. I'd like the second app to expose the service to other apps, which is why I was assuming there would need to be an actual .svc file somewhere in the second app that exposes the service.

Comment: The service is exposed by the managed process which runs the ServiceHost. This can be a windows service, a consle app, or IIS. If you are hosting the service in IIS is when you need a .SVC file.

Comment: And if using an exe as per my example, you need to copy the relevant bits of App.config from your service (contents of <system.serviceModel>)

Answer (score 1):

The service is exposed by the managed process which runs the ServiceHost.

This can be a windows service, a consle app, or IIS.

If you are hosting the service in IIS is when you need a .SVC file.

If you are not hosting in WCF you should create a app.config file which will tell the WCF runtime how you want your service to be exposed. To do this use the `<System.ServiceModel/>` config section.

Once the service is hosted it can be consumed by any number of client applications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a partial implementation of the service in the host project. Keep in mind a WCF service technically is just another .NET class. The exposure of it is just the ServiceHost code that references the class's type or .svc file (if exposing via IIS). And VB/C# won't make any difference.